# DocuSign integration for Dynamics CRM 365 - GetSignatures fails

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

We and our customers are using Dynamics CRM online and DocuSign integration.
Since the last 10 days our customers are receiving an issue in the GetSignatures workflow step.

The error message is:

```
DocuSign.DSIntegrationActivity.GetSignatures: System.Exception: Unable to deserialize the returned JSON. Endpoint: GetSignatures.
Error Description: Error checking sharepoint folder for /Opportunity (Unknown) Server Response
{"Error":"Unknown","ErrorDescription":"Error checking sharepoint folder for /Opportunity"}
```

Our customer has the DocuSign integration solution version 6.2.2.0

Can you please help us to solve the issue?
Thank you

Comment: DocuSign is a commercial product, you need to contact their customer support

Comment: thx for the hint. DocuSign directs developers to StackOverFlow. That's why I ask here :)

Comment: their developers can point to where they want, but from the text you posted is clearly an error from their side (workflow activity or the API that is called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our customers reported that the issue has been solved.
No update or change is required in Dynamics CRM to fix the issue.
DocuSign fixed the issue on the DocuSign side.

Answer (score 0):

This related to your SharePoint mapping either having been changed or Document Management being setup wrong. You need to go through the process described in [this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/administering-dynamics-365/dn894710(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)